# Azure Function App is not comes under Logic app Designer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have created a new Azure function app.
Using my visual studio I have done the deployment.

After I deploy my function application, I can find it here

(Function application name - **MainFunctionApplication** ,function name - **TestFunction**)

[image]

[image]

But in logic app designer - after I add an action ->

**Choose an operation - **Azure Function** then select my function **MainFunctionApplication**
after that, it should load existing functions. but that part doesn't work.getting empty one like this.
how to fix this scenarion?
[image]

its http trigger
[image]

[image]

Comment: What trigger do you use?

Comment: Please check last image - its httpTrigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try providing the binding directions in and out to the HTTP trigger?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#example

Also, functions that used custom routes did not show up in the logic app action selector. Try to remove the custom routes and it should work fine.

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/621

Comment: please check my last image. can I get it fixed once I remove that routing?

Comment: It's worth making a try, please.

Comment: yeh thats true :)

I tried that 
 public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "null")]
            HttpRequestMessage req, string name, TraceWriter log)

and this way as well 
 public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]
            HttpRequestMessage req, string name, TraceWriter log)
        {

removed complete routing part., still not working.

Comment: it took a while to refresh & your solution is correct.Thanks, @Vignesh G